# What is the most reliable/easiest machine learning algorithm/technique for generic object detection using a ZED camera?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, camera, computer-vision

I am doing a school project using the ZED Camera (neither the ZED 2 nor the Mini), and until a week ago, I was under the impression that the built in API was sufficient for what I need. Long story short, I am using the Camera's Distance Sensing mode—which returns a 760x1280 point cloud with each point having the distance from the camera at that point in the image the camera collects—to determine if a moving robot is heading towards an object, and if so, what direction to turn. I am not necessarily trying to identify *what* the objects are, but merely *if* there are any objects. I am very new to the realm of machine learning, and while I'm aware that this issue is probably very simple, I simply do not have enough of a background, or enough time, to fully delve into the problem, and so I'm asking for a nudge in the right direction.
To recap, I need to determine if the robot is approaching an object of any size, and if so, how far away the object is in addition to which direction is best for navigating around it. The camera has API for TensorFlow, PyTorch, and a few other machine learning frameworks. After some research, it appeared that TensorFlow was the most supported/real-time, and so if using TensorFlow/Keras is an option than that would be preferred, however any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the most useful thing would be if you could create your own dataset. It'll be a simple classification problem. Take many recordings with the camera (with objects: class 1), and (without objects: class 0).

Then, use a simple 3D CNN model to train a classifier. You can use tensorflow.keras to prototype a model really fast.

This is how a very simple 3D CNN looks in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=sample_shape))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Conv3D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax')) # 2 as you have 2 classes
```

Comment: This is something that I had considered, but had heard from different instructional videos/websites that generally machine learning models require dataset sizes on the range of *millions* of items, and I don't have the time to create 1,000,000+ different scenarios. In your experience, is that true? Especially in my case where I'm just wanting to detect the presence of objects, not necessarily the type of object?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can get a working model with few thousand samples depending on your need.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is a bit vague when you ask for the most **reliable and easiest ML algorithm**, there are a couple of options which are already implemented for ZED camera. [Zed yolo](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-yolo) and [Zed tensorflow](https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-tensorflow) repos should be a good option for you. They are easy to setup and launch.

They achieve the following objectives you're looking for:

- Detect an object in front of camera.
- Report its distance from camera.

Both the repos use demo weights trained on [COCO dataset](http://cocodataset.org/#home). If your objects do not match the objects in COCO dataset, you should consider training your own network for your custom objects. You can have a look at [darknet repo](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet#how-to-train-to-detect-your-custom-objects) on how to do that for Yolo.